# Кавычки и конкатенация строк в PHP

Tags: php, html, css, строки, char

Проблема с встраиванием строки. Нужно, чтобы в `url()`, было следующее: `'/path/to/file/img.jpg'`. Строка (без одинарных кавычек) хранится в `$_SESSION['img']`. Желаемый результат: `url('/path/to/file/img.jpg');`

```
echo '<body> <div id="img" style="background: url();"></p> </body>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    echo '<body> <div id="img" style="background: url(\''.$_SESSION['img'].'\');"></p> </body>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно это:

```
<?php 
    echo '<body> <div id="img" style="background: url('.$_SESSION['img'].');"></p> </body>';
?>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Так, насколько мне известно, изображение не будет отображаться. Посмотрите мой ответ. Все же спасибо.